# vim python-mode ошибки запуска

Tags: python, vim, python-mode

При первом открытии любого python-файла показываются следующие ошибки:

```
Обнаружена ошибка при обработке function pymode#init:
строка    2:
E121: Неопределённая переменная: import
строка    3:
E121: Неопределённая переменная: sys
строка    4:
E121: Неопределённая переменная: sys
Обнаружена ошибка при обработке /home/dmitriy/.vim/bundle/python-mode/autoload/pymode/virtualenv.vim:
строка    3:
E121: Неопределённая переменная: from
Обнаружена ошибка при обработке function pymode#breakpoint#init:
строка    9:
E15: Недопустимое выражение: << EOF
строка   11:
E492: Это не команда редактора: from importlib.util import find_spec
строка   13:
E121: Неопределённая переменная: sys
строка   16:
E488: Лишние символы на хвосте: else:
строка   23:
E170: Отсутствует команда :endfor
```

часть .vimrc с настройками python-mode:

```
" отключаем автокомплит по коду (у нас вместо него используется jedi-vim)
let g:pymode_rope = 0
let g:pymode_rope_completion = 0
let g:pymode_rope_complete_on_dot = 0


" документация
let g:pymode_doc = 0
let g:pymode_doc_key = 'K'


" проверка кода
let g:pymode_lint = 1
let g:pymode_lint_checker = "pyflakes,pep8"
let g:pymode_lint_ignore="E501,W601,C0110"


" провека кода после сохранения
let g:pymode_lint_write = 1


" поддержка virtualenv
let g:pymode_virtualenv = 1


" установка breakpoints
let g:pymode_breakpoint = 1
let g:pymode_breakpoint_key = '<leader>b'


" подстветка синтаксиса
let g:pymode_syntax = 1
let g:pymode_syntax_all = 1
let g:pymode_syntax_indent_errors = g:pymode_syntax_all
let g:pymode_syntax_space_errors = g:pymode_syntax_all


" отключить autofold по коду
let g:pymode_folding = 0


" возможность запускать код
let g:pymode_run = 0


" Disable choose first function/method at autocomplete
let g:jedi#popup_select_first = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как всегда ответ приходит именно тогда, когда перепробовал все варианты от других пользователей (да, уже гуглил ошибки и на ру, и на англ сайтах) и уже задал свой вопрос тут...

Если вкратце, то в начале файла .vimrc (выше нет его) была такая строчка:

```
let g:pymode_python = 'python'
```

И проблема была в том, что плагин не видел сам питон и нужно было добавить `3` в конце (так):

```
let g:pymode_python = 'python3'
```

Вопрос решен, теперь все работает. Ошибок нет, функционал весь от python-mode получил. Извиняюсь за создание лишнего вопроса на сайте. Но зато это может кому-то помочь, у кого возникнет схожая проблема.